# (SSRS v.15) How do I obtain a group's each individual totals outside of the group?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-expression

My query includes 4 groups. **Category** > **Type** > **Activity** > **Nature** > detailPrice.

I have the report built with 4 different List Items stacked into each other. Each list is one of the four groups. The detailPrice is a table (pink).[Each of the 4 groups has a different colored border, to differentiate (just for testing).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EDbi.png)

Each list shows a Total of the previous list. List 2 (Activity) shows the sum total of the entries in List 1 (Nature), and so on. The total of List 4 (Category) shows the grand total of all the previous lists.

My 3rd List's group (Type) is always split into two sections: Revenue and Expenses. So there are two totals in the 3rd List's grouping: the first is 90033, the second is 37627.
[Here's the total of Revenue. Only the first number matters, which is 90033.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTn3q.png)

Inside my fourth list (Category), rather than just show the grand total (of Revenue - Expense), I want to show both the total of Revenue and Expenses, and then show the grand total.
For the Grand Total, I simply sum the proper field. But I am unable to get the 90033 and 37627 I need.

I've tried many different options:

- When the 3rd list sums the Revenue, I put that value in a custom code variable, and then the same with Expenses. `=IIF(Fields!Type.Value = "Revenue", Code.addTotal("R",SUM(Fields!detailPrice.Value))` (the function simply adds the detailPrice to one of two variables: totalR and totalE depending on the first parameter)
- I tried the same with a Report Variable `=IIF(Fields!Type.Value = "Revenue", Variables!totalR.SetValue(SUM(Fields!detailPrice.Value)))`
- I also tried Running Values, but didn't get very far.
- I can't simply access the ReportItem!total of the 3rd group, as I am trying to get it from outside the group.

After all my attempts, my two variables (totalR and totalE) have the same value: 37627. I can never get 90033 as well as 37627. I can get the total of Expenses... but not Revenues. I feel like the total of the Expenses group overrides the Revenue value, but I have no idea how to keep that 90033 to use it outside of the group.

Is it possible to reference each total in a group outside of said group?

Comment: Are each of the totals used only in one box? You could try to reference the textbox. =ReportItems!TextBoxName.Value

Comment: @papermoon88 Thanks for answering! Hmm.. the two problems I see with that (when I tried it) is that the two totals are in the same textbox (the same textbox duplicated for each total), so each total doesn't have a unique textbox name... and since I'm trying to reference said totals outside of the group, it won't let me use the !ReportItems command.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a new dataset for the totals?

Comment: I was hoping it would not have to come to this, but I think that's how I will have to do it. Create a new dataset entry for those individual totals. Thank you for helping! I'll make sure to do that when I can.